# TypeError: this.getInciData is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, class

I am trying to call the function inside the same class with other function but I am getting **TypeError: this.another is not a function** error

```
Custom.Widgets.report.Incidents = RightNow.Widgets.extend({ 
    constructor: function() {
        this.getViewData();
    },
    another: function(){
        alert("Calling another function");
    },
    clicked: function(){
        $("#firstPage").click(function(){
            alert("Calling function on Click"); */
            another();
        });
    },

    getViewData: function(){
        alert("Calling main function");
        this.another();
    },

});
```

Please help,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not bound to the function but you can bind it like this:

```js
const obj = {
  another: function() {
    console.log("Calling another function");
  },
  getViewData: function(){
    console.log("Calling main function");
    this.another.bind(this)();
  }
};

obj.getViewData();
```